# HOWTO add request header to breeze batch requests

Tags: odata, breeze, asp.net-web-api2

Note that this is not the same thing as adding a header to the parent request as mentioned in this other tread: [Breeze - Adding headers to request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458916/breeze-adding-headers-to-request).

I'm using the Breeze webApiOData dataservice & need to add a specific header value within each request within a batch. I can add the header value to the parent request (using the afore mentioned link), but that isn't included in the child request. In my specific instance, I need to include an antiforgery token to the request. Batch requests are split out into individual requests by the WebApi Odata controllers and as such, they don't see the parent request. I'm exploring how to tweak the server side code in the that validates the anti forgery token, but that (1) only addresses my specific challenge and (2) doesn't help with others who may need to include a header value in the request.

I'm using breeze v1.4.12... looking at the source, it appears the headers are being explicitly set (lines 15280-15284 & line 15380)... so it isn't clear to me if it is even possible to override and control the inner header for individual requests within a batch at present time.

Specifically, I'm controlling the inclusion of the antiforgery token in the request like this with breeze:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true);

var unsecuredClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;
var securedClient = {
  request: function (request, success, error) {
    request.headers.RequestVerificationToken = jQuery("#__RequestVerificationToken").val();
    return unsecuredClient.request(request, success, error);
  }
};
OData.defaultHttpClient = securedClient;
```

When I look at the request sent to the server, I see the token in the primary request's header, but not in the inner request:

```
POST https://localhost:44362/odata/$batch HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:44362
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 585
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
RequestVerificationToken: fNR1OqB3SxNLF5EUI9mb-partial-rest-ommitted
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0
Origin: https://localhost:44362
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_2a9d-ba3e-cf5f
Accept: multipart/mixed
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Referer: https://localhost:44362/Home/SPA
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=jtfbzyt4zqk5pu43p1qop5tl; FedAuth=ommitted


--batch_2a9d-ba3e-cf5f
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_1fec-c63e-5864

--changeset_1fec-c63e-5864
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

POST odata/Projects HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 1
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=fullmetadata;q=0.7, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
Content-Type: application/json
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0

{"Id":-1,"Type":"SP.Data.Research_x0020_ProjectsListItem","eTag":null,"Title":"test"}
--changeset_1fec-c63e-5864--

--batch_2a9d-ba3e-cf5f--
```

And when you look at the raw response, you can see how it fails to find the token in the header (confirmed when I step through the code on the server-side):

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batchresponse_efc71196-045b-474c-bfe3-e21e20ae64b0
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
DataServiceVersion: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcRGV2XFJlcG9zaXRvcmllc1xtc2Z0c3BjYW1yaVxzcmNcU3BSZXNlYXJjaFRyYWNrZXJcb2RhdGFcJGJhdGNo?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 29 May 2014 16:42:00 GMT
Content-Length: 4432

--batchresponse_efc71196-045b-474c-bfe3-e21e20ae64b0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changesetresponse_aa3c98d6-a059-454d-9477-00e0b9497278

--changesetresponse_aa3c98d6-a059-454d-9477-00e0b9497278
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-ID: 1
Content-Type: application/json; odata=fullmetadata; charset=utf-8
DataServiceVersion: 3.0

{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"An error has occurred."
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"The required anti-forgery cookie \"__RequestVerificationToken\" is not present.","type":"System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException","stacktrace":"   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken, AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase httpContext, String cookieToken, String formToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgery.Validate()... bla bla bla"
    }
  }
}
--changesetresponse_aa3c98d6-a059-454d-9477-00e0b9497278--
--batchresponse_efc71196-045b-474c-bfe3-e21e20ae64b0--
```

**@UPDATE -** For a stopgap we've implemented a process where when the request is initially received serverside (using a custom ODataBatchHandler, overriding the ValidateRequest() method), we grab the tokens from the parent request and store it in cache. Then when we validate the request within the controllers, we first check to see if the property is in the request (which is actually the inner request of the batch as once the controller gets the request, the batch has been split up into multiple requests) and if not, we then see if it is in cache, effectively looking at the parent request. It's important to remove the value from cache, as we do in our (ProcessBatchAsync() within the custom ODataBatchHandler) otherwise you're introducing a security hole keeping it around for more than one request.

Answer (score 2):

Good catch!

The problem is in the `createChangeRequests` method (line 15380) which doesn't support any custom tweaking of the inner request.

We'll discuss internally to find a way to address this formally. Short term I can't think of a work-around other than to create a custom copy of the OData dataservice adapter with a change to this fnc. Yuck.

What's your timeframe?

Comment: Whew... good to know my perception was correct :) Awesome to hear it will be addressed! I've added our current workaround to my initial post for others as a stopgap.

Comment: You can handle this scenario as of v.1.4.14 with the [**`changeRequestInterceptor`**](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/controlling-ajax#changeRequestInterceptor).