# Add header to request in breeze while making a request to a ODATA server

Tags: odata, breeze

I am creating an application. My server is ODATA server and I am using breeze at client side. Can anyone please tell me how I can add a header before making a request to server? `breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax")` is not working for me.

```js
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');//,'angular',true);

ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
    headers: { "Auth" : "I am not a hacker" },
};

breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "webApiOData" });
```

Comment: Sorry but getting the adapter instance is not enough to add a header -could you please add what code you have tried so far?  If not then just check the docs, it shows you how there.

Comment: var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');//,'angular',true);
        ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings = {
            headers: {

                "Auth" : "I am not a hacker"
                
            },
        };
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "webApiOData" });

I think that i am adding header in the wrong adapter. That is why i was wondering if there is any adapter available in breeze to make ODATA request.

Comment: By the way, which docs are you talking about.. i have searched a lot but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The webApiOData dataService adapter does not use the ajax adapter configured in Breeze, so adding default headers to the ajax adapter does not work. You will have to configure datajs instead. See [Breeze - Adding headers to request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20458916/breeze-adding-headers-to-request)

```
var oldClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;

var myClient = {
    request: function (request, success, error) {
        request.headers["Auth"] = "I am not a hacker";
        return oldClient.request(request, success, error);
    }
};

OData.defaultHttpClient = myClient;

breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "webApiOData" });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using below code now-
var oldClient = OData.defaultHttpClient;
        var myClient = {
            request: function (request, success, error) {
                request.headers.Authorization = $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
                return oldClient.request(request, success, error);
            }
        };

        OData.defaultHttpClient = myClient;
        breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ dataService: "ODATA" });
It is not hitting the server anymore..  I tried with dataService WebApiOData as well but didn't work..

Comment: just wondering if you know whether adapter.changeRequestInterceptor will work.. is it possible to make changes in dataService adapter using adapter.changeRequestInterceptor and configure it for ODATA Server..??

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I've updated the Breeze documentation on ["Configuring AJAX"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/controlling-ajax#odata-ajax) with a similar recommendation.

Comment: The **Breeze OData adapters do support `changeRequestInterceptor`** which operates in the Breeze layer rather than at the AJAX level. That's the right interceptor for manipulating the *inner* details of the $batch requests. The authorization header in your example belongs on the *outer* $batch request which is out of reach for the `changeRequestInterceptor`. Therefore, you'll need to make the adjustment to the DataJS `OData` component as explained here.

Comment: Hi.. Can you please tell me how to get the URL generated by breeze? I am using Code :-
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Partners");
manager.executeQuery(query, function (data) {
var results = data.results;
...............................
}

Comment: @user3773872 Not sure what you mean, but you should post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found the following solution:

```
.run(['appConfig', 'breeze', '$http', function (appConfig, breeze, $http) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common[appConfig.antiForgeryCookieName] = appConfig.aftoken;
        var adapter = (breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true));
        adapter.headers[appConfig.antiForgeryCookieName] = appConfig.aftoken;
    }
```